# Changing integer shown in tabPage.text with a button click in c#

Tags: c#, numbers, int, buttonclick, tabpage

I cant seem to change the integer shown in tabPage.text with a button click in c#.

I have tried to change it to a string, but that did not help.

The number "24" shows on the tabPage, but it wont increase or decrease when I press the button. Any ideas?

Here is the code :

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        static int ledigeRom = 24;    
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }            
        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }               
        private void Rom1_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {                  
           if (Rom1.BackColor == Color.Red)
            {
                Rom1.BackColor = Color.Green;
                ledigeRom++;
            }    
            else
            {
                Rom1.BackColor = Color.Red;
                ledigeRom--;
            }            
        }
```

And here is the code from Form1.Designer.cs :

`this.tabPage1.Text = "1.Etasje " + ledigeRom;` (thats why the static of the int)

Comment: can you please explain your question?

Comment: check the added answer.

Answer (score 1):

you should use variable instead of Static.

> int ledigeRom = 24;

Comment: But then I won´t get the variable in Form1.Designer.cs?

Answer (score 0):

Change your `Rom1_Click_1` event as

```
  private void Rom1_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {                  
       if (Rom1.BackColor == Color.Red)
        {
            Rom1.BackColor = Color.Green;
            ledigeRom++;
        }    
        else
        {
            Rom1.BackColor = Color.Red;
            ledigeRom--;
        }   
     //include this
      this.tabPage1.Text = "1.Etasje " + ledigeRom;          
    }
```

Comment: Thank you. This worked. Could someone explain why, so I learn from it?

Comment: after changing the value of `ledigeRom` again you have to set to the tab's text, so that you can get the updated value.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (button1.BackColor == Color.Red)
            {
                button1.BackColor = Color.Green;
                this.tabPage1.Text="1.Etasje" + ledigeRom++;
             }
            else
            {
                button1.BackColor = Color.Red;
                this.tabPage1.Text = "1.Etasje" + ledigeRom--;

            }  
        }
```